# PTIJ: What kind of Jew was Mordechai?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We are told that Mordechai is *ish yemini* -- a man of the Right [Esther 2:5]. He insists on a two-day Purim, since he lives in the Diaspora [Esther 9:21].  This implies a tendency towards traditionalism.

But then he accepts to be dressed in "royal garb" before being paraded through the streets, without worrying about the shaatnez issue [Esther 6:10-11].  And he accepts a document signed by a woman, Queen Esther, mandating the observance of Purim forever [Esther 9:29-31]. He was popular with "most" of his brethren, not "all", indicating disapproval by the more observant Jews [Esther 10:3]. All this clearly reveals his left-wing sympathies.

And his name...  Mordechai, after the Persian god Marduk.  That's like a Jew today calling himself Timothy or Christian.  Was he even Jewish?

So, will the real Mordechai please stand up?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Although this is a non-serious question, it can also be a serious question discussing the religious observance of Morchai and Esther- https://alhatorah.org/Mordechai's_Religious_Identity

Comment: I think you have to be careful in the way questions are phrased. Although it is Purim Torah we have to be careful not to be disrespectful of a tzaddik.

Comment: He was Yemmenite. That explains everything.

Comment: And to add, the gemara in menachos 64b brings an opinion of mordechai. Rashi understands this to mordechai from the purim story. Tosfos, on the other hand says the discussion took place hundreds of years later, and it couldn't be the same person. Rather, tosfos suggests that mordechai was an honorary title bestowed upon a leading sage.